# 404 on route refresh in angular 4, nginx server and apache

Tags: angular

I created a new component in Angular 4 and added its route 'account'.
When I run `ng serve` home page opens and there is a link to account page.
On clicking account page link account page opens. If I refresh the page, it works.

The problem is that when I make build with `ng build` and upload build to apache. If I click on 'account' link the account page opens. 
But if I refresh or try open account route directly i get 404 error on.

If I add 'use hash', then it works with '#', but I don't want this.

I am using angular 4.2.4

Comment: All you need to do is to modify your apache .htaccess file such that all request serve index.html fie. further routing is done by the angular scripts loaded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check this [Link](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/wiki/Deploying-prod-build-to-Apache-2) on how to deploy Angular Apps on Apache.

**How to Serve index.html in apache**

> This can be achieved by adding a .htaccess file (in the same directory where the index.html resides) with the following contents.
>
> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>   RewriteEngine On
>   RewriteBase /
>   RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>   RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
> </IfModule>
> ```

Comment: Please credit your sources, and don't copy content verbatim. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284988/angular-2-404-error-occur-when-i-refresh-through-the-browser/35285068#35285068

Answer (score 2):

Try adding query_string in your nginx conf file

```
location / {
    alias /var/www/my_project/dist/;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$query_string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In back-end (server side) just map all (404) error/unrecognized requests to your index (which includes all angular build scripts).then it returns the index. In front-end, u can get what u need.It maps to the page which u need.

eg:- 
[In spring Boot back-end this is an example answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42865084/redirect-unknown-requests-to-index-html-in-springboot)

Comment: You should include the relevant information in your answer in case that post gets deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Just put this on .htaccess in root

RewriteEngine on

```
# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite everything else to index.html
# to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```